# PHP in Nginx being downloaded instead of rendered?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm sure this is kind of a duplicate question, but I've tried googling this to no avail. I'm trying to make a site that will just run a php script on a button press. I'm trying to get php to work right, so I have an info.php file here:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now, whenever I try to go to this file in my webpage it just tries to download it instead of render it. I feel like I've tried everything under the sun to fix this, but I have no clue whats going wrong with it.

Here's my default nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;
    listen [::]:8000 default_server;
    server_name jarofmilk.com www.jarofmilk.com;

    root /var/www/jarofmilk.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php5-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            #fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

PHP Version:

```
   php --version
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16 (cli) ( NTS
```

Nginx Version:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Ubuntu Version:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
```

I appreciate any insight. I've already uninstalled and reinstalled php.
I'm sure this is a repeat question, but I've looked over most of the other stackoverflow results, and nothing worked for me.

Here's php-fpm.conf:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: none
pid = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php7.0-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been design to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lower priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless it specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is build with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in second, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - /usr otherwise
include=/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/322018/nginx-not-executing-php-files ??

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839601/php-file-downloads-instead-of-executes-with-nginx

Comment: yeah, my question wasn't answered, the thread it gave me was pretty much unrelated from what I was trying to fix.

Comment: Show your php-fpm pool configuration

Comment: I just added php-fpm.conf up above ^^

Comment: Where is the pool configuration? see `include=/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf`

Comment: Can you `restart php7.0-fpm` for a test?

Answer (score -2):

I just figured it out! It was a problem with my nginx.conf. Apparently I had written it all wonky when I first was setting it up.

I followed examples from [This site](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/) and it works now :)